# Is "pre-checking" the preferred way to avoid adding None-types or empty strings when doing double recursion on lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return, nonetype

I'm doing some recursion exercises on lists in python3 and was running into a problem where I would have my returned list filled with some unwwanted None-types.

This particular exercise is for creating a function that removes all vowel strings from a list. All the elements in the input list are strings of length one, but the list can contain more lists as well.

```
def without_vowels(arg):
    vowels = "aeiuoåäöAEIUOÅÄÖ"

    if not arg:
        return arg

    elif isinstance(arg, str):
        if not arg in vowels:
            return arg
        else:
            return ""

    elif isinstance(arg, list):
        if without_vowels(arg[0]) == "":
            return without_vowels(arg[1:])
        else:
            return [without_vowels(arg[0])] + without_vowels(arg[1:])
```

Expected output:

```
>>> test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
>>> without_vowels(test)
>>> [['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```

Initially, to "remove" the vowels upon detection I would simply not return anything. This resulted in None-types being added to the list.

Output without work-around (lines 10,11, 14-16 removed) :

```
>>> without_vowels(test)
>>> [None, ['h', None, 'j'], ['t', None, 's', 'c', None]]
```

To work around this problem I changed the code to return an empty string when vowels where found, and added a "pre-check" before calling on the function again to continue, basically just checking if the function call would find a vowel (and return "") and in that case skip ahead to the next part of the list argument.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and there should be a better solution without using a work-around like this.

Thanks

**Edit:** This particular exercise is meant to be solved with double recursion, not with a combination of iteration and single recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This particular exercise is meant to be solved with double recursion,
>   not with a combination of iteration and single recursion

My approach to recursion is to keep it simple and let the recursion do the work for you:

```
VOWELS = set("aeiuoåäöAEIUOÅÄÖ")

def without_vowels(argument):

    if not argument:
        return argument

    head, *tail = argument

    if isinstance(head, list):
        head = without_vowels(head)
    elif head in VOWELS:
        return without_vowels(tail)

    return [head, *without_vowels(tail)]
```

**USAGE**

```
>>> test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
>>> without_vowels(test)
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want for a "better solution".  What I see as the straightforward way is to delete the vowels from anything you encounter, recurring on the elements that are sequences.  I did one step with this:

```
def without_vowels(arg):
    vowels = "aeiuoåäöAEIUOÅÄÖ"
    if not isinstance(arg, list):
        return arg

    result = [c for c in arg if not isinstance(c, str) or c not in vowels]
    for idx, c in enumerate(result):
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            result[idx] = without_vowels(result[idx])

    return result

test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
print( without_vowels(test) )
```

Output:

```
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```

I don't know that it's (yet) cleaner than yours, but it does avoid directly inserting and then removing empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it in a single List-comprehension, but I am too tired to make it work.

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
def without_vowels(arg):
    vowels = "aeiuoåäöAEIUOÅÄÖ"
    returnList = []
    for entry in arg:
        if type(entry) == str and entry not in vowels:
            returnList.append(entry)
        elif type(entry) == list:
            returnList.append(without_vowels(entry))
    return returnList

test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
print(without_vowels(test))
```

And the output of the above code:

```
>>> without_vowels(test)
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```

Edit: I suppose that my solution would give back an empty list, if the only entry in a list is a vowel, but if that's okay, then this should do the job.

Comment: Yes returning an empty list should be fine when the only elements in the list argument are vowels.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following implementation makes the your question moot:

```
VOWELS = set("aeiuoåäöAEIUOÅÄÖ")

def without_vowels(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        return [without_vowels(item) for item in arg if without_vowels(item)]
    elif isinstance(arg, str):
        non_vowels = [ch for ch in arg if ch not in VOWELS]
        if len(non_vowels) > 2:
            return non_vowels
        elif len(non_vowels) == 1:
            return non_vowels[0]
        return non_vowels

test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]

print(without_vowels(test))  # -> [['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```